# Mailgraph.cgi script error

Tags: perl, cgi, graphing, rrdtool

I have installed rrdtool 1.4.7 and on testing with http://localhost/mailgraph.cgi.I get the error below:
Premature end of script headers: mailgraph.cgi, referer: http://localhost/mailgraph.cgi.

How can i get over this.Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

mailgraph.cgi does not send out HTML headers correctly.

Check the apache error/access log for details.

You could check the script itself from commadn line.

```
./mailgraph.cgi
```

It should output soething like this:
    Content-type: text/html

```
<HTML>,<DOCTYPE (or some other HTML coode)
```

Check this link: http://oreilly.com/openbook/cgi/ch12_01.html

regards,